# Конвертировать python-программу в exe файл

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

У меня есть программа:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        print('VideoCapture read no frame')
    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Video', gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('k'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Хочу преобразовать в .exe файл. Python версии 3.6, операционная система Windows 10.
P.S. Уже попробовал cx_Freeze и pyinstaller. Не преобразовывает. cx_Freeze просто не создает папку build, а pyinstaller создает папку, но когда я запускаю .exe файл, то он сразу же закрывается.

Comment: Если файл сразу закрывается, попробуйте запустить его из cmd, и посмотрите какие ошибки пишет.

Comment: cx_Freeze при "упаковке" какие-то ошибки пишет?

Answer (score 5):

Если компилировать программу на python всё-таки нужно, то скачиваем cx_Freeze с [http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cx_freeze](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#cx_freeze) (так как в ней нет одного неприятного бага, который есть в официальной версии).

Затем устанавливаем, не забывая правильно выбрать директорию, где расположен python.
[image]
Установка cx_Freeze

Компиляция

Создаём в папке с программой файл setup.py с содержимым:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
    name = "Имя",
    version = "Ваша версия float или int",
    description = "Ваше описание",
    executables = [Executable("Путь к файлу")]
)
```

Переходим в командную строку (обычно Пуск → Стандартные → Командная строка). Переходим в папку с программой (в моём случае D:\Dima\py). Запускаем команду C:\Python34\python.exe setup.py build (вместо C:\Python34 нужно написать папку, куда установлен python).
[image]

Начнется процесс сборки, в котором cx_Freeze может выдавать предупреждения, но, скорее всего, они не повлияют на работу программы.
[image]
Предупреждения в процессе компиляции
Запуск exe файла

Заметьте, не файл, а папка! Все остальные файлы также нужны для работы программы (да, это недостаток cx_Freeze). К тому же, при завершении программы окно сразу закрывается (а не ждет нажатия клавиши), поэтому в конец программы нужно дописать что-то вроде:

```
input("Press Enter")
```

И скомпилировать ещё раз.

Также можно создать msi-архив командой C:\Python34\python.exe setup.py bdist_msi.

Разумеется, при компиляции более сложных программ вы можете столкнуться с более сложными проблемами.

Для их решения следует воспользоваться официальной документацией: https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/.

Источник: https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/program-compilation-with-cx-freeze.html

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/283781)

Comment: Я уже пробовал так делать, но я не могу включить модуль cv2!!!

Comment: @TimSafonov Что еще за cv2?

Comment: @Suvitruf так пойдет?

Comment: @TimSafonov, что означает "я не могу включить модуль cv2"? Какую-то ошибку выдает? Всю дополнительную информацию внесите в вопрос.

Comment: @VerNick, так не норм. Не нужно копипастить всю статью (обратите внимание на комментарий Suvitruf: *"лучше указать здесь самое главное"*, но не копипастить все). К тому же, вопрос был не как пользоваться cx_Freeze, а что есть проблемы при работе с cx_Freeze.

Comment: @VerNick, см. в Справке: **[Как ссылаться на материалы, написанные другими](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)** - *"Не копируйте полный текст из внешних источников; вместо этого используйте их слова и идеи для поддержки своих."*

Comment: @insolor Ок, сейчас исправлю

Comment: При использовании cx_Freeze с программой в которой есть cv2(он же opencv): "C:\Users\Admin>python setup.py build
running build
running build_exe
C:\Users\Admin>" и папка build не создается. А при использовании pyinstaller  .exe файл компилируется, но при его запуске он сразу же закрывается и ничего не происходит.

Comment: @TimSafonov Прочитайте последние строки после изображения в моем комментарии.