# как скомпелировать .py в .exe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, exe

Как скомпелировать `.py` файл в `.exe`?
конечно можно сделать всё через `pyinstaller`, но в таком случае если у человека не скачан `Python` скрипт попросту не запуститься...

Comment: py2exe например

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Конвертировать python-программу в exe файл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/869375/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-python-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2-exe-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb)

Comment: нет, там соверешенно другая проблема, у меня pyinstaller работает но я хочу чтоб программа запускалась на компютерах на которых не скачан Python, а там проблема в том что pyinstaller не работает

Comment: работает.  не забываете --onefile или отдавайте всю директорию. может не работать, если собран на 64x а запускается на 32х